# multiple insert 2 table using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello excuse me please help me, I have a problem when I add a lot of data to 2 tables.
following the code that I have made

```
$this->db->trans_start();

$result = [];

foreach($data1 as $key => $val){

    $response["pesan"]="";

    $result[] = [
        "data1"  => $data1[$key],
        "data2"  => $data2[$key],
        "data3"  => $data3[$key]
    ];
}

$this->db->insert_batch('table1', $result);

$last_id = $this->db->insert_id();

$result1 = [
    "data1" => $data1,
    'data2' => $data2
];

$this->db->insert('table2',$result1);
$this->db->trans_complete();

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: what is your error? Are you facing any error?

Comment: you can't use `insert_batch` alongside with `insert_id` it will gv you back only the last inserted id - which obv. is your last item in your array...

Answer (score 0):

i think you should follow mvc pattern.